# swift 2 collection for sorting a key value pair by value

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, nsarray

I am using swift 2 to access microsoft's emotion api. This returns a json object that is placed into an NSArray then dictionary like so:

```
`let info : NSArray =  (json.valueForKey("scores") as? NSArray)!

                let anger: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("anger") as? Float
                let contempt: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("contempt") as? Float
                let disgust: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("disgust") as? Float
                let fear: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("fear") as? Float
                let happiness: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("happiness") as? Float
                let neutral: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("neutral") as? Float
                let sadness: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("sadness") as? Float
                let surprise: Float? = info[0].valueForKey("surprise") as? Float

                emotions.append(anger!)
                emotions.append(contempt!)
                emotions.append(disgust!)
                emotions.append(fear!)
                emotions.append(happiness!)
                emotions.append(neutral!)
                emotions.append(sadness!)
                emotions.append(surprise!)

                let dictionary = [
                        "anger" : [emotions[0]],
                        "contempt" : [emotions[1]],
                        "disgust" : [emotions[2]],
                        "fear" : [emotions[3]],
                        "happiness" : [emotions[4]],
                        "neutral" : [emotions[5]],
                        "sadness" : [emotions[6]],
                        "surprise" : [emotions[7]]
                    ]
```

i need to get the values sorted because the largest float will determine the emotion, so i have to keep the key to know what the mapped emotion is. What would be the best collection to do this, i already know a dictionary is not meant to be sorted.

Comment: How do you need to access the data later on?

Comment: the highest value will be added to a UILabel to show the user

Answer (score 0):

This code extracts the first dictionary of the JSON `scores` array like you did but returns if there is nothing there.  Then it (1) removes all elements except the emotion keys that you are interested in, (2) converts the remaining emotion values to `Float`, and (3) returns a tuple of the largest valued element. Ignore the tuple's second value (emotion score).

```
let keys = ["anger", "contempt", "disgust", "fear", "happiness", "neutral", "sadness", "surprise"]

guard let info = (json.valueForKey("scores") as? Array).first else { return }
let (emotion, _) = info
  .filter { (k, _) in keys.contains(k) }
  .map    { (k, v) in (k, Float(v)) }
  .maxElement()
```

You can now use the value of `emotion` in your UI as needed.